# I need some help creating a query and a database table to retroactively assign numbers to existing table

Tags: php, mysql

As my info states, I inherited the job of statistician for a local dart league. (Woohoo $20 a season)

I would love to implement an ELO rating system.

The current database table has over 100,000 entries.

There are 3 different games that are played. Singles, Doubles, and Team.

The originator of the database has the games entered as such:

```
Index   Player1_num   Player2_num   Opp_Player1_num  Odd_Player2_num   H_team  V_team Season     Week   W   L  Game_type
```

A singles game is entered twice.

```
values(1,20,null,30,null,200,300,11,2,1,0,301_singles)
```

and

```
values(2,30,null,20,null,200,300,11,2,0,1,301_singles)
```

It was done this way to facilitate easier look-ups of individuals.

A doubles game would have values such as

```
(3,20,21,30,31,200,300,11,2,1,0,501_doubles)
(4,21,20,30,31,200,300,11,2,1,0,501_doubles)
(5,30,31,20,21,200,300,11,2,0,1,501_doubles)
(6,31,30,20,21,200,300,11,2,0,1,501_doubles)
```

There again, it is built for easier queries for looking up wins and losses across seasons and with different partners.

A team game is:

```
(7,null,null,null,null,200,300,11,2,1,0,team_game)
```

So I added a match_num column to the table to help lump the games under 1 number.

However, I am unsure how best to assign the numbers, understandably, I don't feel like going through all 90k entries by hand.

Note: The early seasons were modified by hand and not all double matches have 4 entries (some only have 1). Some matches may be out of order as well (Instead of indexes: 1,2 they could be 1,9).

I don't know if you need more info for this, and I am unsure of how to post larger examples of the table.

```
Current code: 
<body>
<?php
include "inc.php";
// Select Max Match Number
        $sqlMatch="select max(match_num) from stats_results";
        $match =mysql_query($sqlMatch);
        $m= $match ? mysql_result($match,0):mysql_error();
        $matchno= $m+1; // First Match number

$game=array("'301_singles'","'cricket_singles'","'501_singles'","'301_doubles'","'cricket_doubles'");


// selects max season
    $sqlSeason="select max(season_index) from stats_season";
    $season =mysql_query($sqlSeason);
    $smax= $season ? mysql_result($season,0):mysql_error();
#          $smax=2; 
// for each season up to  max season
            for($s=1;$s<=$smax;$s++)
                    {

// Selects max week within the current season
                    $sqlWeek="select max(week) from stats_results where season=$s ";
                    $Week =mysql_query($sqlWeek);
                    $wmax= $Week ? mysql_result($Week,0):mysql_error();
#                        $wmax=2;
// for each week within current season up to the max week
                    for ($w=1;$w<=$wmax;$w++)
                            {

// each singles game
                            foreach($game as $g)
                                    {

###########################################################################################################



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats_results where season=$s and week=$w and game_code=$g ;") or die(mysql_error());

// Put them in array
for($i = 0; $rows[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++) ;

// Delete last empty one
 array_pop($rows);
//******************************************************

$matches=array();
foreach($rows as $record)
{
    // Get a unique match code for this match
    $matchid= getMatchID($record);
    // Have we seen this ID before? If yes add this record index to the existing array
    // otherwise create an array with just this value
    if (!isset($matches[$matchid])) $matches[$matchid]= array($record['index_results']); // No
    else $matches[$matchid][]= $record['index_results']; // Yes, add this Index
}
// Now $matches is an array of arrays of Index values, grouped by "match" so...

/* Sort $matches by key (see getMatchID for why!) */
ksort($matches);

// Update the table 
foreach($matches as $match) 
{

    // Create SQL instruction to set the match_num for all the Index values in each entry
       $sql= "UPDATE stats_results SET match_num = $matchno WHERE index_results IN (".implode(",", $match).")";
echo "<br>";
echo $sql;
/* Execute the SQL using your chosen method! */

// Move the match count on
$matchno++;
}
// End our loops
                                    }
                            }
                    }

function getMatchID($gamerecord) 
{
$index= "{$gamerecord['season']}-{$gamerecord['week']}-{$gamerecord['game_code']}-";


$players= array(
   $gamerecord['player1_num'], 
   empty($gamerecord['player2_num'])?0:$gamerecord['player2_num'], 
   $gamerecord['opp_player1_num'], 
   empty($gamerecord['opp_player2_num'])?0:$gamerecord['opp_player2_num']
); 
// Sort the players to get them in a consistent order
sort($players);

// Add the sorted players to the index
$index.= implode('-', $players);
return $index;
}


?>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it important that the match numbers are sequential? (So match #112 is guaranteed to have occurred before (or at least in the same week as) match #113 for example?)

Comment: @danielpsc not really. What I have done so far: create array of games, find max seasons, do a loop from min to max seasons, find max week per season, loop through seasons. find max and min indexes based upon week,season. (hope that made sense) and what I still need to think through So my next step is to do a loop on index meating criterea of week and season. For each index look up player 1 and player 2, then lookup index+1 through max index and compare player2 of that result to player 1 of first result and vice versa.

Comment: @danielpsc Actually, as I think ahead, it will be important. I plan on next taking the match numbers to start doing the ELO computation. I think it will work better if they were chronological.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm putting this into an Answer so I can get it to layout a bit better - but it's not really a "solution" as such!)

I think what I'd do is try and build an array of arrays of `Index` values grouped by game - you can then use that to create SQL to update the table.

So, if `$rows` is an array of all records we'd do something like the following pseudo-code:

```
$matches= array();

foreach($rows as $record)
{
    // Get a unique match code for this match
    $matchid= getMatchID($record);
    // Have we seen this ID before? If yes add this record index to the existing array
    // otherwise create an array with just this value
    if (!isset($matches[$matchid])) $matches[$matchid]= array($record['Index']); // No
    else $matches[$matchid][]= $record['Index']; // Yes, add this Index
}

// Now $matches is an array of arrays of Index values, grouped by "match" so...

/* Sort $matches by key (see getMatchID for why!) */
ksort($matches);

// Update the table 
$matchno= 1; // First Match number
foreach($matches as $match) 
{
   // Create SQL instruction to set the match_num for all the Index values in each entry
   $sql= "UPDATE games SET match_num = $matchno WHERE Index IN (".implode(",", $match).")";

   /* Execute the SQL using your chosen method! */

   // Move the match count on
   $matchno++;
}
```

So all that leaves is the `getMatchID` function - if we give each match a temporary ID based on it's season, week and a sorted list of it's participants (and use the Season and Week first) that should be unique for each game and we can sort by this index later to get the games in the right order. So again in rough pseudo-code, something like:

```
function getMatchID($gamerecord) 
{
   $index= "{$gamerecord['Season']}-{$gamerecord['Week']}-{$gamerecord['H_Team']}-{$gamerecord['V_Team']}-";

   $players= array(
       empty($gamerecord['Player1_Num'])?0:$gamerecord['Player1_Num'], 
       empty($gamerecord['Player2_Num'])?0:$gamerecord['Player2_Num'], 
       empty($gamerecord['Opp_Player1_Num'])?0:$gamerecord['Opp_Player1_Num'], 
       empty($gamerecord['Opp_Player2_Num'])?0:$gamerecord['Opp_Player2_Num']
   ); 

   // Sort the players to get them in a consistent order
   sort($players);

   // Add the sorted players to the index
   $index.= implode('-', $players);

   return $index;
}
```

So all being well `$index` would come back with something like `11-2-200-300-0-0-20-30` for the first singles match in your example - no matter which of the game records we were looking at.

Does that make sense/help at all?

Comment: On the surface I knda get what you are going for, but, as you can see by my coding, it is a bit above my ability right now, but I will run with it and see if I can make sense of it and put it in to use. My level of understanding is a basic 1d array, I hear my brain sizzling thinking of an array of arrays. Give me a day to digest this.

Comment: So my first question You said $rows as all records, I assume you are suggeting `$rows=select * from stats_results` or am I completely misinterpretting this.

Comment: That's exactly right. Basically we just need to run through every record to make sure we can give them all a match number.

Comment: I am not sure how much you are willing to help me with this beyond the great effort you have already done. I am still a huge noob at this coding business and am unable to troubleshoot some of what you wrote. Did my query, good. then did  a `print_r($players)` and got `Array ( [0] => [1] => 0 [2] => [3] => 0 )` repeating a bunch of times (50-70 times). Feel free to tell me  I am beyond help...I'll understand.

Comment: I've just tweaked my code to fix an issue with the creation of the `$players` array (it didn't handle Team matches (with no players specified) properly). In terms of debugging the interesting thing to print will be `$index` just before the end of the `getMatchID` function. It should be a something like `11-2-200-300-0-0-20-30` - if you get something closer to `----0-0-0-0` that suggests that `$gamerecord` isn't getting set properly. If you don't mind adding your code so far to your question I'll try and help debug if you like.

Comment: To be honest I didn't change too much from what you posted. I figured i would step through it changing stuff as I found it broken. You had mentioned psuedo code, but it looked pretty complete. I posted current code.

Comment: I think the problem is probably with the field names - I just noticed in my code, for example, I'm using `Player1_Num`, `Player2_Num` etc, whereas in the question you had `Player1_num` etc (lower-case "n"). So we'd be getting blanks all the time. Can you check the field names against the database and correct them so they match. (Sorry, should have been more careful!)

Comment: OK I just modified the the cases and I am now getting arrays such as :`Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 0 [2] => 55 [3] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 0 [2] => 3 [3] => 0 ) ` which is what I expect from the $players array :)

Comment: Excellent. So, hopefully you'll also be getting sensible values from `$index`?

Comment: print_r($index) is showing `----0-0-3-55` and `----0-0-3-55` WHich seems to be sorting properly

Comment: It's losing Season, week and the teams though - I think, in my code again, `$row['Season']` should be `$row['season']` - same for week. Also `$row['H_Team']` needs to be (I think) `$row['H_team']` and same for `V_team`

Comment: I will double check that, also in the UPDATE, how is the 'WHERE Index IN` working? and is the `index` in `array($record['Index'])` your Index or the stats_results table's index?

Comment: The index in `$record['Index']` is supposed to be stats_results table's index - i.e. something that uniquely identifies one line in the results. The `WHERE Index IN` is the same - `Index` needs to be the name of stats_results index field. So we're building an array of arrays of `Index` values, grouping them by a string which should uniquely identify a single match, then updating the records in the group to have a sequential match number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43065/discussion-between-bill-flippen-and-danielpsc)

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the definition of `function getMatchID(...)` **isn't** inside your loops (maybe just move it to the very top of the file) otherwise it won't get defined. Otherwise you should be OK...

Comment: I though I deleted the comment quick enough. thanks for the reply, I had indeed thrown my closing brackets below the function, moved the closing brackets before the function and all is well, I want to cycle through  1 week at a time for the first few seasons to do an audit of the matches. Still gotta refine the query and the loops but I am now well on my way to achieving the goal. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ok I spent the last few days going line by line of of the results restricting the query 1 week at a time. (got through week 3). I found some erroneous data in the data base and will be using this tool to help ID more and correct it, but I ran the code with the looping and it is now genrating some errors: `UPDATE stats_results SET match_num = 81 WHERE index_results IN ()` is one another is `UPDATE stats_results SET match_num = 105 WHERE index_results IN (204)` if I run it 1 week at a time it produces `UPDATE stats_results SET match_num = 105 WHERE index_results IN (203,204)`

Comment: I think the problem might be with the `$rows` array - unless I'm missing something I don't think that's getting reset for each game, so it the number of games in each iteration isn't exactly the same you'll start to get problems. If you add `$rows= array();` at the top of the `foreach($game as $g) {` loop that should fix that problem.

Comment: So I added a `print_r($rows)` right before the and I think I can somewhat see a cause...or at least a symptom. First loop developes Array 0-80. 80 is empty. `[80] => )` Showing the SQL first update fine. If I remove the `pop_array` I get what appears to be the same result in the Array, but the first SQL update is an empty set `()`.

Comment: so leaving the `pop_array` in... looking further down the second iterition is for the cricket games Array is 0-80 as well with the last one being empty, SQL updates look good as well.

Comment: On the 3rd iteration, I get 501 singles entered into the array, but entry 40 is blank and entry 41 is loading cricket_singles again. Looking back at the second iteration entry 41 is the same as the third so you may have something to your suggestion:)

Comment: Adding the `$rows=Array() did the trick. The 501 array ended at entry 40 then started th esql update. I added previous comments to help others if they needed aid in troubleshooting. I, once again, am indebted to you